# Which project should I add .Net Core Identity (Web API or in Web Client)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created 2 separate projects a Web API and MVC as a Web Client.  I wanted to add an external login for my web client, and now I'm confused on which project I should put the Identity stores.

By the way I am using .Net Core 3.1 with VS Code as my editor.

Comment: In my opinion, this should be based on your requirement. If the web client contains some useful information and the web api and the web client hosted at same server, you could enable the identity in the web client and set the web api only receive intranet access.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your opinion. I just thought that it would be better if all the business logic and data access have to be put in the Web API since we can protect them with some security features like token authentication by using AAD for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not complete (there is not enough information on how You going to use API).

In most cases, the .Net Core **Identity system should be used in an API**, since often APIs contain the main logic of the application being implemented, and clients are just interaction interfaces (of which **there can be several**, for example, a mobile application and a web interface).

You also mentioned that You are using VS Code as code editor. It doesn't have built-in code generation capabilities like VS does, but you can still use **dotnet CLI codegenerators** (e.g. [ASP Identity scaffolding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=netcore-cli)).

Comment: thank you for the response and for sharing idea on how the API should work. It was these days that I am planning to implement the awesomeness of .Net Core Identity. And as I go with my research, I was worried about UserManager and SigninManager on how to effectively use them.

Comment: But now, you somehow clarifies things out of my confusion thank you :)